# How do you add files to projects?

Tags: c#, winforms

Im currently trying to add 2 files to my project. One of them is a .ovpn (vpn Config file) and the other is a batch file.

Im trying to create a directory in my code and then add these files to that newly created directory so when the users first run's this application it creates the files needed to run the application.

Is there anyway of adding these files like a resource so I can just reference them easy?

Sorry if this is a really simple question. Just never done it before.

Thankyou in advance!

Comment: Maybe adding the files as embeeded resources and extracting them at runtime as needed?

Answer (score 2):

You can try to change properties of your files like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to necessarily have them embedded in the executable to have them easily referenced.

Add a 'resources' type object to your project - call it Resources.res
Right click on your project, make a New Folder
Call it 'Resources' - add your resource files in here.
Double click on your Resources.res file
Click on the 'Add New Existing File'
Navigate to your file that is in the Resources directory and select it.
You should see your file showing up inside the resources viewer now.

When you are writing code, you can now reference your added files via:

```
Resources.<nameoffile>
```

If your file is a text file, you can do things like

```
string jsonRequest = Resources.RegistrationRequest;
```

This should automatically set the files to be embedded as well, so they should be accessible at run time.

Comment: They need to be embedded into the file, I want the application to be portal. Therefore I can't grantee that every user is going to have this config file. That is why I want my application to provide it instead of them having to find it.